# publishing android app for specific country

Tags: android, google-play, android-market-filtering

I have some doubts regarding android market developer console ,if anybody could help me on this it will be greatly appreciated.

> 1. I have published my first free app into the market before some days.I have selected all countries from the publishing option. Now my
>      customer wants that it should be visible only for Australia. I have
>      deselect all countries and select only Australia and save that.but my
>      app is still visible in android market for India and Germany.I haven't
>      do any changes in the apk file so i have not touch the Unpublish
>      button.Is this a right way to make app country specific ?
> 2. How may times i can change the product details ? Is there any restrictions for that..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I believe it takes a rather long time until these changes are made visible on the market (1-2 days). How long has it passed?
2. There is no restriction as far as I know